# Changing from netbeans to VS. NB had no errors. VS found some and I can't fix them

Tags: c++, visual-studio, netbeans

```
template <class T>
void InFront<T>::escreve(ostream& ostr) const {
vector < deque <T> > aux = vet;
for (size_t i = 0; i < aux.size(); i++) {
    ostr << "Sequencia: " << i << endl;
    for (size_t j = 0; j < aux[i].size(); j++) {
        ostr << aux[i].front() << endl;
        aux[i].pop_front();
    }
}

ostr << endl;
}
```

This is the error:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

It happens on this line

```
ostr << aux[i].front() << endl;
```

On NetBeans it ran but changing to VS showed the previous error. I had to switch i from int to size_t already, can't I use i anymore?

Comment: `#include <string>`, got one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely didn't `include` the headers you need. Add this

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: I didn't. Why didn't NetBeans complain about that and VS does?

Comment: I'm not sure why NetBeans was okay with that, I only use Visual Studio (when I'm on Windows). You should always get in the habit of including every header that you use, don't rely on the IDE/compiler to connect the dots for you.